# ERROR: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps (NextJs / Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

Today I started to build a Next.js application.
I am using Redux (`next-redux-wrapper`) to manage my global state.
(I am also persisting some reducer with redux-persist).
I just implemented `redux-thunk` and immediately got a very strange error. I really do not know why that error is occurring. I basically just did the setup, without creating any reducers (The error was still there, after I created the reducer).
It is not the first time, I did the same setup without any problems, but that time I can not get rid of that error.

Error code

> Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not
> recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See
> https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.***
>
> - ***Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.***
> - ***If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization*** ***techniques or move it to static
>   getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at:
>   https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state Please update the following
>   components: withRedux(MyApp)

If you need more code, please ask. I just do not really have much more. Maybe `package.json`.

_app.js

```
import App from 'next/app'
import { wrapper } from '../reduxStore/store'
import { useStore } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const store = useStore((state) => state)
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.func,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object,
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp)
```

store.js

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { HYDRATE, createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer'

const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
})

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state, // use previous state
      ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
    }
    // if (state.count.count) nextState.count.count = state.count.count // preserve count value on client side navigation
    return nextState
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action)
  }
}

export const makeStore = ({ isServer }) => {
  if (isServer) {
    //If it's on server side, create a store
    return createStore(reducer, bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]))
  } else {
    //If it's on client side, create a store which will persist
    const { persistStore, persistReducer } = require('redux-persist')
    const storage = require('redux-persist/lib/storage').default

    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'nextjs',
      whitelist: ['user'], // only counter will be persisted, add other reducers if needed
      storage, // if needed, use a safer storage
    }

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer) // Create a new reducer with our existing reducer

    const store = createStore(
      persistedReducer,
      bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]),
    ) // Creating the store again

    store.__persistor = persistStore(store) // This creates a persistor object & push that persisted object to .__persistor, so that we can avail the persistability feature

    return store
  }
}
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore)
```

Comment: The problem is here of the library you are using: https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/blob/7.0.2/packages/wrapper/src/index.tsx#L190

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the third party library is using `componentWillReceiveProps` - `componentWillReceiveProps` gets automatically renamed to `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`. This happens because those methods are now considered legacy code and [React is deprecating](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) that lifecycle method as well as others.

Unfortunately, their isn't an immediate solution.

- You can fork the code and update it yourself
- Start an issue on the code's GIT page and hope the update their maintainer fixes the issue.
- Find another library to do the same job.
- Write custom logic to do the same thing as the library
- Use the library and hope they fix it before it's deprecated by React.

Comment: Hey Sean thanks for the reply. You can basically just turn off  reactStrictMode in the nextt.config.js. Would you still recommend to use that library. Unfortunately there is no better option :(

Comment: The warning is only shows in development.  I would not disable strict mode to suppress the warning.  The warning is there so  you time to fix you code before React removes it from the framework and it will no longer works.   It's up to you to for the library but it looks like it's on the maintainers radar to be fixed - https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/380#issuecomment-867650258

Answer (score 0):

the error caused by the third-party library  (next-redux-wrapper) about Legacy Lifecycle Methods (UNSAFE), the previous name is componentWillReceiveProps, That name will continue to work until version 17.

### to fix it

you can use the `react-codemod` to automatically update your components. and use rename-unsafe-lifecycles property

```sh
npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles <path>
```

my path to a third party library is
path=`./node_module/next-redux-wrapper/lib/index.js`

thank you